# We overstayed us for 3 months will it affect my uk visa

Tags: passport

I overstayed us for 3 month as my wife was pregnant but we had also valid visa for 5 years but the cbp officer just stamped our passport to stay 18 days in us when we entered us

since my wife was about to deliver baby we applied for extension and  we stayed for 3 months after applying for extension

but now i am worried both me and my wife we have 5 years valid uk visa so we just need to know will my uk visa be affected in future will they make us any problem at immigration

Comment: Please rewrite this question using capitals and punctuation  where needed ('**I** overstated **in the US**'). The US part is (more or less) clear, but the UK part not at all. Paragraph 1: US Visa part. Paragraph 2: UK visa part. Paragraph 3: The question why the US overstay effects the UK (I assume) the UK residence permit. At present this is not readable.

Comment: Thank you Mark , i have made the corrections thank u so much.

Comment: @Nilesh Are you talking about an overstay in the US? You refer to an extension - was that approved? Is your UK visa a 5 year visitor visa or a residence permit? What is your citizenship?

Comment: I wouldn't write "I overstayed us for 3 month" and admit I did something wrong until I was sure. For some immigration requests, if you file the paper work on time, your stay is extended until the USCIS decides on your request. Since you didn't say exactly how you requested an extension, and when this happened (the rules are constantly changing) it's hard to say if you got an extension while the request was being considered or not. You might want to hire a US immigration lawyer to answer your questions; it's not easy for a layman to figure out what the rules used to be a few years ago.

Comment: @Gerard: OP is worried about a U.K. visa, not a US visa. U.K. will likely look at exactly what happened, and decide if what happened makes it more likely that OP won’t leave the U.K. when their U.K. visa runs out.

Comment: @gnasher729, if it turns out that just filing the application extended the time the OP was allowed to stay in the US, then there was no overstay. When answering questions on a UK visa application, if asked if the OP had ever overstayed anywhere, the OP could answer "no" (assuming the incident in the US was the only questionable incident).